# Can emotional IQ be learned?

Tags: emotion, intelligence, iq

Can emotional IQ be learned? This question concerns both the general population and those with lower than average emotional quotients such as individuals with Asperger's, or Autism spectrum disorder for example.

Comment: I'm looking at this article on EI, and it mentions that it is more of a skill and knowledge than intelligence, and as such it should be possible to learn it and get better at it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_intelligence#Criticisms_of_measurement

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about those with lower than average.. BUT
Emotional Intelligence can be learned.

Read on:
http://www.lifehack.org/articles/communication/7-practical-ways-improve-your-emotional-intelligence.html

http://www.wikihow.com/Develop-Emotional-Intelligence

This will not be a process of a few hour, nor a few days.. It will take you a few weeks or months to grasp and, maybe, a few years to have something robust.
You have only positive "things" to gain if you go this route

Answer (score 0):

Yes, emotional IQ is attained through past experiences and through how the individual is able to learn from his surrounding about himself and strengthen his/her basic characteristics one should exhibit in  main areas: self-awareness, emotional control, self-motivation, empathy and relationship skills(Borsic Lab et al., 2019).

refrence : Borsic Lab, Z., Burbano, K., Gallardo R, V., Bangeppaga, M., Mulla, S., & Selvanayag, M. (2019). Emotional Intelligence Models as Generators of BusinessManagement Change in the Human Talent Area. Journal Of Artificial Intelligence, 12(1), 1-10. doi: 10.3923/jai.2019.1.10